# How to customize token sending while using OAuth2 in OpenApi 3 with password flows?

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, openapi

I am looking for the proper way to specify an Authorization header and not send the word 'bearer' with my token

The custom Authorization header should look like

```
authorization: 'myToken'
```

All my attempts to specify the securitySchemes entry with type: OAuth2 seems to produce other results...

The closest I got is something like:

```
  securitySchemes:
    Authorization:
      type: oauth2
      description: This API uses OAuth 2 with the password grant flow.
      flows:
        password:
          tokenUrl: oauth/token
          scopes: {}
```

... but this generates the **authorization: 'bearer myToken'** header instead of **authorization: 'myToken'**.

How can such a requirement be specified?